# Python How can I create sets for every item in my list?

Tags: python

How can I create sets for every item in my list?

This is my list:

```py
listofstrings = ['sdfasdf', 'sdfaserth', 'wegoiog']
```

I want it to create sets like this:

```py
set1 = set(), set2=set(), set3=set()
```

Comment: `[set(i) for i in listofstrings]` ?

Comment: You want to create empty sets for every element in the list. That makes no sense

Comment: I agree with @kuro, as it is currently presented this question is nonsensical.

Comment: To follow up on my comment, I think the most likely scenario is that OP is very new to programming and this is a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/628382).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create as following:

```
for index, word in enumerate(listofstrings):
    exec("set%d = %s" % (index + 1, set()))
```

Comment: Why would you use `exec()` for this!?

Comment: @ Alexander Cécile Because he wanted different variables for each words not list or dict. You can share your answer without exec(). I would like to see.

Comment: If OP does want to dynamically create a bunch of variables, then this is clearly a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/628382).

Comment: @Alexander Cécile That is upto ethtrhaef. You can't decide on his behalf what he wants? He stated the input and output and answer satisfy that.

Comment: Oh and your `index + 1` could be done away with if you used `enumerate()`’s `start` parameter.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile To me it sounds that the answer fits perfectly to the question. It may have been wise to add a warning about using `exec()`, which is a problematic structure in `python` (google it), but I really don't see why we should avoid answering questions, just because maybe the OP really wants something else.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Actually that part was meant for the answerer (that he is the one who can put a warning in his answer), but you also didn't seem to mind about the usage of `exec()`, apart from that you think it is not what the OP wanted to ask.

Comment: @Aryerez Let me reassure, I **absolutely** mind the use of `exec()` lol

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of them like this

```
sets = []
listofstrings=['sdfasdf', 'sdfaserth', 'wegoiog']
for string in listofstrings:
    sets.append(set())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary to do it(so you can access each set matching the corresponding string).

```
name_to_set = {}
listofstring = ['sdfasdf', 'sdfaserth', 'wegoiog']
name_to_set = {name: set() for name in listofstring}
```

so later you can use it as follows:

```
name_to_set['sdfasdf'].add('x')
```

Comment: Could have also done `name_to_set = {name: set() for name in strings_list}`.

Answer (score -1):

As I mentioned, this question is unclear and probably a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/628382). I feel the need to share a solution because so many of the current ones are bizarre at best.

```py
list_of_strs = ['sdfasdf', 'sdfaserth', 'wegoiog']

sets_list = [set() for _ in list_of_strs]
```

Notice I changed the variable names. In Python, variable names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Why are you creating a list when the output say to generate dynamic variables. Do you know the use of exec() method in python?

Comment: @TamoorSalah-U-Din _Why are you creating a list when the output say to generate dynamic variables._ Because as if often the case with these kinds of questions, a list or dictionary is sufficient. The reference QA for this is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables.